# Excel VBA and Solver: How to suppress dialog box that pops up after hitting time or iteration limits?

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I use the standard Solver which is part of Excel 2010 in a loop, and every now and then the whole process is halted and a dialog box pops up saying that the maximum number of iterations has been reached, even though I provide UserFinish:=True to the SolverSolve function.
It prompts the user to continue, stop or abort the procedure. As you can imagine, this is very annoying when you let the machine run alone at night and get up the next morning to see that it got stuck somewhere in the middle.

I'd like to suppress these annoying prompts by pre-defining an answer ("stop!" and move on to the next optimization) to these problems.

Unfortunately, via Google, I've only found attempts to solve this problem, but not definitive answers.

What's today's state-of-the-art solution to this problem, which I assume must be encountered by many users?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

there is a sample solution to a similar question in another answer:

it uses the SolverSolve PassThru method to call a function to handle the solver result at each iteration.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984584/catch-max-time-iteration-dialog-box-when-using-excel-solver-in-vba/4049124#4049124)