# VBA Solver disabling the dialog box that pops after each iteration

Tags: excel, excel-2007, solver, vba

I am using the built-in solver in Excel 2007 within a VBA loop to solve a number of different problems. Occasionally, the solver hits the maximum time, which causes a pop-up dialog box to appear asking whether the user wants to Continue, Stop, or End. In all cases I want it to end, and proceed to the next line of the loop. This will prevent a user from having to sit there and respond each time.

I ran a macro with the solver pass thru method ([Catch max time/iteration dialog box when using Excel Solver in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984584/catch-max-time-iteration-dialog-box-when-using-excel-solver-in-vba)) but then it gives me another dialog box saying "The formula you typed contains an error"

I also tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197237(v=office.15).aspx .
Which is a less complicated version of 'The solver pass thru method' but after each iteration it gives me the same message as "The formula you typed contains an error"
This is my code

```
Sub Optimize()
'
' OptimizeShortfall Macro
'

'
Set MyFirstObj = Range("I124")
Set MyFirstRange = Range("H600:H698")
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To 1
    MyObj = MyFirstObj.Offset(0, i).Address
    MyTestRange = MyFirstRange.Offset(0, i).Address
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:=MyObj, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:= _
        MyTestRange
    SolverAdd CellRef:=MyTestRange, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="100%"
    SolverOptions MaxTime:=20, Iterations:=100, Precision:=0.000001, AssumeLinear _
        :=False, StepThru:=False, Estimates:=1, Derivatives:=1, SearchOption:=1, _
        IntTolerance:=5, Scaling:=False, Convergence:=0.0001, AssumeNonNeg:=True
     SolverSolve UserFinish:=True, ShowRef:="SolverIteration"
    Next i
End Sub

Function SolverIteration(Reason As Integer)
    MsgBox Reason
    SolverIteration = 1
End Function
```

Comment: The `ShowRef` argument is optional. You can omit it, in which case the loop will run to the next solver problem. The message `The formula you typed contains an error` implies that something else is wrong, possibly in the model setup.

Comment: If i omit the ShowRef argument i get the dialog box saying "Max time limit reached, do you want to Stop/continue". To avoid this i used ShowRef to call the macro 'SolverIteration' but then it gives me a msg saying "The formula you typed contains an error".

Comment: Could you report which line gives the error? Can you also check that all formulas are entered without any typos? Sometimes issues such as having semicolons instead of commas in the formulas, or many levels of nesting, can give such errors.

Comment: The line with 'SolverSolve' function after it has finished the optimization gives the error. I think specifically the ShowRef argument, because when omitted it does not give me the formula error but instead gives me the 'Max time limit reached' dialog box.

Comment: I see. In theory your code should work, but the error message you are getting is very hard to debug, because it can mean anything. [This post](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/555406-solved-solver-solversolve-showref.html) has exactly the same symptoms, but the real problem was completely different. Do you have any events in your code? If events fire up and attempt to change the solver cells, then this might be a problem..

Comment: @loannis: Thanks a lot dude!!!! The link you gave me solved the problem. My workbook name had space in it as well as it was some 20 characters long. I chaged it to single letter and now the macro works!
Thanks a lot dude!!! This has been stalling my work for so many days!

Comment: Cool! If you have a moment, could you write an answer explaining the solution (and then accept it as well)?
This will give you some reputation points (so it's nice!), but also will help others who might bump into this problem. It seems that is is an undocumented bug that only the link above gives an answer, so it is helpful to have it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197237(v=office.15).aspx ,  will explain to you clearly when a dialog box appears, what it means and how to avoid it if you are running solver in a loop.

One force Solution to go to the next loop in case Max Time/Iterations were reached was  to keep the Alt+T button pressed for the duration of the whole macro.

Another wiser method is to use The ShowRef argument in the SolverSolve function.
What ShowRef does is instead of poping a dialog box, it will run the macro given to it as an argument, in this case "SolverIteration". If you want the solver to continue for the given Iteration set SolverIteration to 0. If you want to stop the solver for the given Iteration and move to the next Iteration, Set SolverIteration to 1.

Do take a note that the ShowRef Argument has some issues in digesting workbooks with very long name and/or names with space in them, So set the name of the workbook as short as possible.

Sorry if my explanation wasn't sufficient enough for you. Here is the exhaustive list of three links that i needed to solve my problem:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197237(v=office.15).aspx

[Catch max time/iteration dialog box when using Excel Solver in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984584/catch-max-time-iteration-dialog-box-when-using-excel-solver-in-vba)

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/555406-solved-solver-solversolve-showref.html

P.S. In my code mentioned in the above question, just remove the line 'MsgBox Reason' from the function "SolverIteration".(It just causes another dialog box to pop up with an Integer of value Reason on it :P)