# When loop and solver dialogue box (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro that runs various cases for different probabilities. Basically, it runs through 216 cases (4 times each)  for various case scenarios, by incrementing values in 3 different cells, and getting solver to calculate the best returns thereafter. It works well for 1 iteration, but there are 864 iterations, which is where the problem occurs.

After each iteration, I get the dialogue box popping up, saying that solver has found a best match and what do I want to do. My question is if there is any way to disable the pop-up?

Code:

```
Sub Macro9()
'
' Macro9 Macro
'

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Integer

a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 1


While a <= 30

    Range("B21") = a

    While b <= 30

        Range("B22") = b

        While c <= 30

            Range("B23") = c

            SolverOk SetCell:="$I$24", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$14:$B$20", _
                Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
            SolverSolve
            SolverOk SetCell:="$I$24", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$14:$B$20", _
                Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
            SolverSolve
            SolverOk SetCell:="$I$24", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$14:$B$20", _
                Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
            SolverSolve
            SolverOk SetCell:="$I$24", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$14:$B$20", _
                Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
            SolverSolve

            Cells(27, d) = d

            e = 28

            While e <= 37

                Cells(e, d) = Cells(e - 14, 2)
                e = e + 1

            Wend

            Cells(38, d) = Range("I24")

            c = c + 5
            d = d + 1

        Wend

        b = b + 5
        c = 0

    Wend

    a = a + 5
    b = 0
    c = 0

    Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

System info: Excel 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had a look around, and the best solution comes from Eyan Noronha's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620884/vba-solver-disabling-the-dialog-box-that-pops-after-each-iteration?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The answer is to include change `SolverSolve` to `SolverSolve (True)`. This allows the solver to keep going through the loop, without displaying the dialogue boxes.