# Using VBA to do constraint minimization

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have a variable `X` which can vary between `A` and `B` and I have a mathematical function `f` which varies with `X`. At `X=A`, `f` is positive, at `X=B`, `f` is negative but there is sweet spot between `X=A` and `X=B` where `f=0` and that it is this spot that I am trying to find. Note that `f` value vary by huge numbers.

Currently what I am doing is iterate between `X=A` and `X=B` and calculate my `f` and see if it is close to zero. This is not working out because if my iteration steps are big, `f` doesn't come close to zero and if my steps are small, the program never finishes running. Is there any other better way you can think of? I am writing my code in vba in excel.

Comment: You can use the built-in Solver Add-in (Excel->Options->Addins->Manage Addins->Solver).  You might need to enable a reference based on your current VBA settings.

Comment: what would the code look like if I use solver? (in terms of X,Y,A,B and f)

Comment: Tough to say without looking at the actual spreadsheet that you currently have.  You probably wouldn't have A & B because these are just starting values for your X & Y variables; so you would have X, Y, & f.  I would put this formula in your spreadsheet so changing either X or Y changes f, then use the Macro recorder to see what the recorded solver code would look like and modify from there.

Comment: This has some userful information about suppressing the solver dialog box when using in VBA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984584/catch-max-time-iteration-dialog-box-when-using-excel-solver-in-vba/4049124#4049124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is sub module that will use Excel's Solver Addin to find the "0" value of a function in cell C2 based on the variables for the function in cells A2 (for X) and B2 (for Y).  If C2 is setup correctly, changing either A2 or B2 will change the value in C2 (you need to have C2 actually be dependent on A2 and/or B2 and A2 and B2 have to be independent).

To install the Addin, make sure you go to File->Options->Add-ins->Manage and ensure that Solver is checked.  Next, open up the VBA editor (Alt+F11), select Tools->References and search for Solver (for me, it was about 8 down and was unchecked).  Check this box to use the reference in your VBA code.

```
Sub findZero()
'
' users solver to find the 0 point of a multi-variable function in cell C2 with variables in cell A2 & B2
'
SolverOk SetCell:="C2", MaxMinVal:=5, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="A2:B2", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

'Following from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984584/catch-max-time-iteration-dialog-box-when-using-excel-solver-in-vba/4049124#4049124
Results = SolverSolve(True, "SolverIteration")
Select Case Results
    Case 0, 1, 2
        ' solution found, keep final values
        SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    Case 4
        'Target does not converge
        'Your code here
    Case 5
        'Solver could not find a feasible solution
        'Your code here
    Case Else
        'Your code
    End Select
End Sub
```